# Multiple GitHub accounts on Jobs

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I know it's possible to merge GitHub accounts, but supposing one would like to keep them separate and yet still feature them all on one's Jobs page, how would one go about that? You can't even add individual projects because it thinks you're not the main contributor, having done it under another name.

Update: You used to not be able to add them. Still, it would be nice to auto-import all of one's projects...adding them one at a time is a bit ridiculous since you're basically copying and pasting every field in from GitHub manually.

Comment: I don't think the developer story has the same limitation. You should be able to just paste the github url when adding an open source timeline item and it should pick it up.

Comment: Exactly, I said so in my update.  I mean linking to multiple accounts a) so they both show up in your header and b) so they auto-import sensibly.

Comment: Yeah, we removed the "Import from GitHub" specifically to allow more than one GH Account, but lost the import as a result. We have plans on a better import feature to address some scenarios.